# plotting the remainder r(n,x) as a function of n

Tags: number-theory

I was graphing the remainder of the Euclidean division between an integer $n$ and an irrational $x$:  $r(n,x) =n-x \cdot \lfloor n/x \rfloor$
when I stumbled on quasi-linear graph I cannot explain. Any idea how to calculate the slopes of the lines and why there is no lines for $x = \phi$, the golden ratio?

[image: r(n,Phi)]:

[image: r(n,Pi)]

[image: r(n,e)]

Comment: You should plot $r(y,x) = y - x \lfloor y/x \rfloor$ for $y \in [0,x]$.

Then $\frac{r(yx,x)}{x}= y -  \lfloor y \rfloor$ doesn't depend on $x$ so when changing $x$ you obtain the same plot but rescaled differently.

Clearly the plot of $y -  \lfloor y \rfloor, y \in [0,1]$ is just a line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, and when plotting $y -  \lfloor y \rfloor, y \in \mathbb{R}$ you get a bunch of line segments from $(n,n)$ to $(n+1,n+1)$.

Thus your question now becomes : what happens when sampling the latter plot at discrete values of $y$ ?

Comment: Why is the slope changing from positive for Pi to negative for e?  Furthermore, the pattern is filled from the bottom right to up-right, then shift right, goes down, etc...Lines only appear if you plot a lot of points, and points on the line do not correspond to the successive value of n.